# rugged is installed but bundler fails to install

Tags: ruby, git, encoding, utf-8, rugged

I am trying to install Gitorious and I want to install the gems required for Gitorious. I am currently running ruby 2.0.0 patchlevel 247 (Most updated as I can get.), and rubygems version 2.0.3. I am also on a shared Dreamhost shared platform using this wiki page http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Gitorious Although it is a bit outdated, I am still getting it to work. When I run `gem install rugged -v '0.19.0'` it returns
`Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed rugged-0.19.0
unable to convert "\x85" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for test/fixtures/alternate/objects/14/6ae76773c91e3b1d00cf7a338ec55ae58297e2, skipping
unable to convert "\xAD" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for test/fixtures/alternate/objects/14/9c32d47e99d0a3572ff1e70a2e0051bbf347a9, skipping
unable to convert "\xED" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for test/fixtures/alternate/objects/14/fb3108588f9421bf764041e5e3ac305eb6277f, skipping
unable to convert "\xE5" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for test/fixtures/testrepo.git/index, skipping
unable to convert "\x8C" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for test/fixtures/testrepo.git/objects/0c/37a5391bbff43c37f0d0371823a5509eed5b1d, skipping
unable to convert "\xCA" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for test/fixtures/testrepo.git/objects/13/85f264afb75a56a5bec74243be9b367ba4ca08, skipping
unable to convert "\xF1" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for test/fixtures/testrepo.git/objects/18/1037049a54a1eb5fab404658a3a250b44335d7, skipping
unable to convert "\xF1" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for test/fixtures/testrepo.git/objects/18/10dff58d8a660512d4832e740f692884338ccd, skipping
unable to convert "\x95" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for test/fixtures/testrepo.git/objects/2d/2eff63372b08adf0a9eb84109ccf7d19e2f3a2, skipping
unable to convert "\x9D" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for test/fixtures/testrepo.git/objects/36/060c58702ed4c2a40832c51758d5344201d89a, skipping
unable to convert "\xA5" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for test/fixtures/testrepo.git/objects/44/1034f860c1d5d90e4188d11ae0d325176869a8, skipping
unable to convert "\xCA" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for test/fixtures/testrepo.git/objects/45/b983be36b73c0788dc9cbcb76cbb80fc7bb057, skipping
unable to convert "\x9D" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for test/fixtures/testrepo.git/objects/4a/202b346bb0fb0db7eff3cffeb3c70babbd2045, skipping
unable to convert "\x9D" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for test/fixtures/testrepo.git/objects/5b/5b025afb0b4c913b4c338a42934a3863bf3644, skipping
unable to convert "\xB3" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for test/fixtures/testrepo.git/objects/60/d415052a33de2150bf68757f6461df4f563ae4, skipping
unable to convert "\xF1" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for test/fixtures/testrepo.git/objects/61/9f9935957e010c419cb9d15621916ddfcc0b96, skipping
unable to convert "\xF1" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for test/fixtures/testrepo.git/objects/68/8a8f4ef7496901d15322972f96e212a9e466cc, skipping
unable to convert "\xF1" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for test/fixtures/testrepo.git/objects/75/057dd4114e74cca1d750d0aee1647c903cb60a, skipping
unable to convert "\xED" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for test/fixtures/testrepo.git/objects/77/71329dfa3002caf8c61a0ceb62a31d09023f37, skipping
unable to convert "\xB3" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for test/fixtures/testrepo.git/objects/81/4889a078c031f61ed08ab5fa863aea9314344d, skipping
unable to convert "\x9D" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for test/fixtures/testrepo.git/objects/84/96071c1b46c854b31185ea97743be6a8774479, skipping
unable to convert "\xCA" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for test/fixtures/testrepo.git/objects/94/eca2de348d5f672faf56b0decafa5937e3235e, skipping
unable to convert "\xF1" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for test/fixtures/testrepo.git/objects/9b/7384fe1676186192842f5d3e129457b62db9e3, skipping
unable to convert "\x9D" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for test/fixtures/testrepo.git/objects/9f/d738e8f7967c078dceed8190330fc8648ee56a, skipping
unable to convert "\x9D" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for test/fixtures/testrepo.git/objects/a4/a7dce85cf63874e984719f4fdd239f5145052f, skipping
unable to convert "\xCA" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for test/fixtures/testrepo.git/objects/a7/1586c1dfe8a71c6cbf6c129f404c5642ff31bd, skipping
unable to convert "\xCA" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for test/fixtures/testrepo.git/objects/a8/233120f6ad708f843d861ce2b7228ec4e3dec6, skipping
unable to convert "\xA5" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for test/fixtures/testrepo.git/objects/b7/4713326bc972cc15751ed504dca6f6f3b91f7a, skipping
unable to convert "\x9D" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for test/fixtures/testrepo.git/objects/be/3563ae3f795b2b4353bcce3a527ad0a4f7f644, skipping
unable to convert "\x9D" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for test/fixtures/testrepo.git/objects/c4/7800c7266a2be04c571c04d5a6614691ea99bd, skipping
unable to convert "\xF1" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for test/fixtures/testrepo.git/objects/c4/dc1555e4d4fa0e0c9c3fc46734c7c35b3ce90b, skipping
unable to convert "\xCA" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for test/fixtures/testrepo.git/objects/e6/9de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391, skipping
unable to convert "\xB3" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for test/fixtures/testrepo.git/objects/f6/0079018b664e4e79329a7ef9559c8d9e0378d1, skipping
unable to convert "\xCA" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for test/fixtures/testrepo.git/objects/fa/49b077972391ad58037050f2a75f74e3671e92, skipping
unable to convert "\xB3" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for test/fixtures/testrepo.git/objects/fd/093bff70906175335656e6ce6ae05783708765, skipping
unable to convert "\xF0" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for test/fixtures/unsymlinked.git/objects/08/8b64704e0d6b8bd061dea879418cb5442a3fbf, skipping
unable to convert "\xB2" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for test/fixtures/unsymlinked.git/objects/13/a5e939bca25940c069fd2169d993dba328e30b, skipping
unable to convert "\xCA" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for test/fixtures/unsymlinked.git/objects/19/bf568e59e3a0b363cafb4106226e62d4a4c41c, skipping
unable to convert "\xBF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for test/fixtures/unsymlinked.git/objects/58/1fadd35b4cf320d102a152f918729011604773, skipping
unable to convert "\x85" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for test/fixtures/unsymlinked.git/objects/5c/87b6791e8b13da658a14d1ef7e09b5dc3bac8c, skipping
unable to convert "\x85" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for test/fixtures/unsymlinked.git/objects/6f/e5f5398af85fb3de8a6aba0339b6d3bfa26a27, skipping
unable to convert "\x95" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for test/fixtures/unsymlinked.git/objects/7f/ccd75616ec188b8f1b23d67506a334cc34a49d, skipping
unable to convert "\x95" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for test/fixtures/unsymlinked.git/objects/80/6999882bf91d24241e4077906b9017605eb1f3, skipping
unable to convert "\xB2" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for test/fixtures/unsymlinked.git/objects/83/7d176303c5005505ec1e4a30231c40930c0230, skipping
unable to convert "\x95" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for test/fixtures/unsymlinked.git/objects/a8/595ccca04f40818ae0155c8f9c77a230e597b6, skipping
unable to convert "\xF0" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for test/fixtures/unsymlinked.git/objects/cf/8f1cf5cce859c438d6cc067284cb5e161206e7, skipping
unable to convert "\x85" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for test/fixtures/unsymlinked.git/objects/d5/278d05c8607ec420bfee4cf219fbc0eeebfd6a, skipping
unable to convert "\xB2" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for test/fixtures/unsymlinked.git/objects/f4/e16fb76536591a41454194058d048d8e4dd2e9, skipping
unable to convert "\xCA" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for test/fixtures/unsymlinked.git/objects/f9/e65619d93fdf2673882e0a261c5e93b1a84006, skipping
1 gem installed`
And when I ran `bundle install` after cloning the mainline repo it returns 
`Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
/home/harborcn/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby extconf.rb --with-make-prog
```

/home/harborcn/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/shellwords.rb:73:in 'shellsplit': undefined method 'scan' for true:TrueClass (NoMethodError)
    from /home/harborcn/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:2409:in ''
    from /home/harborcn/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:47:in ''
    from /home/harborcn/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in 'require'
    from /home/harborcn/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in 'require'
    from extconf.rb:1:in ''

Gem files will remain installed in /home/harborcn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bundler/gems/rugged-76f3382f7eb0 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/harborcn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bundler/gems/rugged-76f3382f7eb0/ext/rugged/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing rugged (0.19.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that gem install rugged -v '0.19.0' succeeds before bundling.`

How do I fix this? Thanks!